# Flutter reduce running gradle assembledebug

Tags: android, flutter

> How i can reduce the time while running flutter app in, it takes more
> than one half an hour often

Command: `Flutter run`

Comment: How large is your project? Which PC specs do you have? One half an hour sounds extreme

Comment: Windows 10, core i5, 4thg, ram 8,It takes about a half an hour every time,  i run the same project without adding other code